# Receive the error while connect the snowflake JDBC connector using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am new to Snowflake + Jmeter.  When i try to config and run the Jmeter using following config, I receive the below error.

```
Data base URL: jdbc:snowflake://uqa13900.us-east 1.snowflakecomputing.com:443/?warehouse=READ_VWH&db=DC&schema=PUBLIC&user=xxxxxx&ROLE=SYSADMIN

Driver class : net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver

UserName : xxxxxx
Password :

Version of Jmeter : jmeter-5.2.1
```

And Lib folder I have placed following jar

1. snowflake-jdbc-3.9.2
2. snowflake-jdbc-3.9.2-javadoc
3. snowflake-jdbc-3.9.2-sources

I am not sure, what i am missing here.Please help.

> *Error Info from Jemter result view** Response message:java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory
>   (JDBC driver encountered communication error. Message: Exception
>   encountered for HTTP request: Connect to
>   uqa13900.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com:443
>   [uqa13900.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com/52.22.81.221,
>   uqa13900.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com/52.201.176.212,
>   uqa13900.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com/34.203.149.228] failed:
>   Connection refused: connect.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there an IP whitelist in effect?  Check with `show parameters like 'network_policy' in account;` A securityadmin can list the IPs: `describe network policy ...;`

Comment: verified by this command, SHOW NETWORK POLICIES. not finding any network policy.

Comment: Could you try using SnowCD from the same client? What kind of output do you receive with this tool? https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/snowcd.html

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string is not valid because it's including port 443. Please remove the port and retry connecting.

You can find in the docs below examples of valid JDBC connection strings:
https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/jdbc-configure.html#examples

Comment: Thanks, i have removed the 443 port. but still i am getting different error.         Response message:java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (JDBC driver encountered communication error. Message: HTTP status=503.)  Modified connection string:  jdbc:snowflake://uqa13900.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com/?user=xxxxx&warehouse=READ_VWH&db=DC&schema=PUBLIC&Role=SYSADMIN

Comment: Please verify that the IP you are trying to connect from is whitelisted as per the below docs: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/network-policies.html